# get streets/houses out of google maps map

Tags: maps

Is it possible to get a list of addresses out of a given map in google maps? If not, are there any services that provide this information?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You might want to have a look at the Google Places API:
https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/

> The Google Places API is a service that returns information about Places — defined within this API as establishments, geographic locations, or prominent points of interest — using HTTP requests. Place requests specify locations as latitude/longitude coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

So you specify a geo rectangle and want to have all streets inside that.
I doubt that there is a service for that.
If you cannot find a service, it is a very demanding task:
You would have to store the vectors of all streets in e.g a spatial database and query for that rectangle. Vector data are available for free at openstreetmap.org, with depending on the country different quality.